# Error when I try to post an image to the API

Tags: javascript, c#, vue.js

I have an API in C#, and with Vue.js I am trying to upload an image by accessing the API. I tried with fetch and axios, nothing changes, and I tried with headers in application/json, application/octet-stream and 'multipart/form-data. I receive a 500 error.

```
async uploadImage() {
 try {
   const formData = new FormData();
   formData.append('image', this.newActivity.selectedImage);

   const response = await axios.post('/api/v1/Images', formData, {
     headers: {
       'Content-Type': 'application/json'
     }
   });

handleImageChange(event) {
     const file = event.target.files[0];

     this.newActivity.selectedImage = file;

     const reader = new FileReader();
     reader.onload = () => {
       this.newActivity.selectedImageURL = reader.result;
     };
     reader.readAsDataURL(file);
   },
```

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> SetImages(ImagesModel imagesModel)
{
   var currentimage = await _imagesRepository.FindByIdAsync(imagesModel.Id);
   if (currentimage == null)
   {
       ImagesEntity imagesEntity = new()
       {
           Name = imagesModel.Name ?? string.Empty,
           CategoriesId = imagesModel.Category_id,
           Created_by = imagesModel.Modified_by ?? string.Empty,
           Created_date = DateTimeOffset.Now,
           Description = imagesModel.Description ?? string.Empty,
           Blob = imagesModel.Blob ?? string.Empty,
           Path = imagesModel.Path ?? string.Empty,
           Url = imagesModel.Url ?? string.Empty,
           Active = imagesModel.Active,
       };
       await _imagesRepository.AddAsync(imagesEntity);
       await _imagesRepository.SaveAsync();
       return Ok(imagesEntity);
```

```
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostNewImage(ImagesModel imagesModel)
{
    HttpClient _httpClient = new()
    {
        BaseAddress = new Uri(AppSettings.UrlApi),
    };
    string oauthToken = await SecureStorage.Default.GetAsync(AppSettings.AuthToken);
    _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", oauthToken);
    var stringPayload = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(imagesModel);
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "/api/v1/Images");
    request.Content = new StringContent(stringPayload, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    return await _httpClient.SendAsync(request, CancellationToken.None);
}
```

Comment: Which Content-Type does your API _expect_ to receive? (That should be clear upfront, and not up to guesswork.)

Comment: Sending `FormData` as `application/json` can not make any sense to begin with.

Comment: Normally it receives application/json

Comment: There is no implementation to "encode" `FormData` as JSON, as far as I know. You likely need to send something completely different from what you are currently sending then.

Comment: C# is the language, but the actual framework is what? .NET? What version?  500 is backend error so there should be something in your IDE output logs giving you a specific error message. It probably has something to do with actual received data type not matching expected data type...  Based on the use of `FormData`, header content-type on the frontend should be `multipart/form-data`.  On the backend, try defining the endpoint as `SetImages(IFormFile file)`.  Whatever `ImagesModel` is, is probably not matching the received data type.

Comment: Well for the backend with .net 8, in fact I have the mobile part in c# to publish an image (I will show the code), it works, but for the web with Vue.js no